# rest api testing using chakram, parameter passing in url using variable

Tags: resteasy, restful-url

I am using chakram for restapi testing.
https://github.com/dareid/chakram

I have two api's chained together.
1st is post request which gives the user id.
post('/login', {"user" : "user1", "password": "password"})

2nd is get request which will use the user id from 1st request and and perform its action of retrieving all its data.
get(/user/{userId}/requests)

I am not able to understand how to pass userId in the 2nd get request, dynamically?

I have tried get(/user/{userId)/requests, {userId: 1001}) but this is not working.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: If the first request actually performs a login and establishes a session, then it will not be necessary to pass the userid in the second request. It could be available from the session.

Comment: its not picking up from the session.

Comment: Of course you have to code that on the server side.

Comment: I did it using string replace and javscript promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved now.

Used Javascript promise to get the head and pass the header to the next api call and also replace the string {userId} with Javascript string.replace(s1,s2).

```
chakram.get(testConfig.APP_URL + testConfig.EMPLOYEE_REQUESTS_API.replace('{userId}', 221), {
                headers: {
                    sessionId: sessionId
                }
```